# Does cloning a git repository create a connection to that source?

Tags: git

I'm trying to learn something about git and how to work with it. However I don't have a complete repository to work with. The site that explains all this stuff says "you can clone mine". But does that create a connection towards this person/company when I commit something? Or did I copy the repository without "a connection" (as I would describe it).

I tried to search for this but it's hard to narrow it down to what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you clone a GIT repo the source repository is automatically added as a `remote` - think of it as a bookmarked URL where it has been cloned from. You can see all saved remotes (there can be more than one) using the command `git remote --verbose`

If you make modifications and commit them you commit them into your local repository.
For sending the committed modification to the original repository you have to use the `push` command.

Note that for pushing a commit you need to have write access to the repository you want to push to. Usually git repositories e.g. at GitHub that don't belong to your account are not writable to you.